# Is there a way to use Emmet with Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey, firefox-addon-webextensions, emmet

I use Firefox's Developer Tools for developing CSS, and it's great, however I have tried many times in the past to get [Emmet](https://emmet.io/download/) support in their code editor without any success. I wondered if any of you wizards had any ideas. I came up with 'snippets' to use with an old text expanding AutoHotKey program called Texter - https://gist.github.com/jeffreykarbowski/280576, I recently had to change computers and I can't seem to get Texter to work any longer.

It would be nice to be able to setup a WebExtension or the likes to have it integrated right into the FF Style Editor [(as a plugin)](https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror-plugin), however, it seems like this has been address already and currently not possible? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088996

Maybe a different port to an AHK script or a Node script that runs in the background? I am not sure, but I don't care for the LiveReload that the Emmet developer put out, and it doesn't work with FF anyways. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!